# getting Sum Floor and Group by to work

Tags: mysql

Ok all i have a question about sum and group by  what i have currently is a error and i don't know how to fix  basically the error is in regards to  this  line of code

```
SELECT PlayerName
    ,floor(SUM(PlayerScore / 500)) + floor(SUM(PPlayerScore / 1000)) + floor(SUM(S4 / 5)) * 2 + floor(Sum(P7 / 3)) * 2 + SUM(prereg) + SUM(st) + SUM(hb) AS BB
    ,floor(SUM(PlayerScore / 500)) + floor(SUM(PPlayerScore / 1000)) + floor(SUM(S4 / 5)) * 2 + floor(Sum(P7 / 3)) * 2 + SUM(PlayerBallots) + SUM(prereg) + SUM(st) + SUM(hb) AS TB
    ,SUM(PlayerBallots) AS PB
FROM player
```

the same issue is throughout the line and it is this 
from this  floor sum command

if 4 players have scores of 1100  1300 1800 and 1000  the sum of that will show 5  when the reality is  it should only show 4 i tried adding in a group by operator it will only show the total for 1 player
is it possible to do what I'm trying or not
thank you in advance

To help a little i will shorten down the code and explain  what i need it to do with an example

```
floor(SUM(PPlayerScore /1000))
```

so for each 1000 points a player scores he gets 1 ballot
so if

jane has 1100 gets 1 ballot floor 1.1

joe gets 1300  gets 1 ballot floor of 1.3

jerry gets 1800 1 ballot floor of 1.8

jane gets 1000 gets 1 ballot floor of 1
the issue is with current code i get 5 when in reality there is only 4 ballots

Comment: 1.1+1.3+1.8+1.0 = 5.2  The floor of that is 5.  Seems to me like it works just fine.

Comment: How would this be 4? Can you explain the math that you would like it to do to arrive at 4?

Comment: You should consider reformatting your code so that it is easier for others to read it and help you.

Comment: A group by on `playername` should absolutely be used here too. Otherwise you are going to end up with some really really strange results (It will do this math for all records, return one line, and pick a random playername to show you).

Comment: yes but the issue is that  player 1 would get 1 player 2  would get 1 player 3 would get 1 and player 4 would get 1  total of 4 the issue  becomes when you get a larger  number source the actual ballots  are 3800  the total will show over 4000

Comment: no it shows the total ballots if i don't use the group but the total ballots will not match as it is  doing the sum  of all the numbers  then dividing and flooring  i need it to do in this order group  by player name for each player  sum score and do  the floor  then sum all the players  ballots